# Difference: LZ77 vs. LZ4 vs. LZ4HC (compression algorithms)?

Tags: lossless-compression, lz4, lz77

I understand the LZ77 and LZ78 algorithms. 
I read about LZ4 [here](http://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/products/crossdevtools/lz4/index.html) and [here](http://fastcompression.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/lz4-explained.html) and found [code for it](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/source/browse/trunk/lz4hc.h?r=113).

Those links described the LZ4 block format. But it would be great if someone could explain (or direct me to some resource explaining):

- How LZ4 is different from LZ77?
- How is LZ4HC different from LZ4?
- What idea makes the LZ4HC algorithm so fast?

Comment: You have multiple questions all tangled together. Have to write a 10 page reply to cover all that.

Comment: @swdev (though wehat you say is true, I gave a shot at writing that big old reply :) )

Answer (score 124, accepted):

[LZ4](https://github.com/Cyan4973/lz4) is built to compress fast, at hundreds of MB/s per core. It's a fit for applications where you want compression that's very cheap: for example, you're trying to make a network or on-disk format more compact but can't afford to spend a bunch of CPU time on compression. It's in a family with, for example, [snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy/) and [LZO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer).

The natural comparison point is zlib's [DEFLATE algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE), which uses [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) and [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) and is used in gzip, the .ZIP and .PNG formats, and too many other places to count.

These fast compressors differ because:

1. They use repetition-detection code that's faster (often a simple [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with no collision detection) but doesn't search through multiple possible matches for the best one (which would take time but result in higher compression), and can't find some short matches.
2. They only try to compress repetitions in input--they don't try to take advantage of some bytes being more likely than others *outside* of repetitions.
3. Closely related to 2, they generate bytes of output at a time, not bits; allowing fraction-of-a-byte codes would allow for more compression sometimes, but would require more CPU work (often bit-shifting and masking and branching) to encode and decode.
4. Lots of practical work has gone into making their implementations fast on modern CPUs.

By comparison, DEFLATE gets better compression but compresses and decompresses slower, and high-compression algorithms like [LZMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm), [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2), [LZHAM](https://github.com/richgel999/lzham_codec), or [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) tend to take even more time (though [Brotli at its faster settings can compete with zlib](https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/)). There's a lot of variation among the high-compression algorithms, but broadly, they tend to capture redundancies over longer distances, take more advantage of context to determine what bytes are likely, and use more compact but slower ways to express their results in bits.

LZ4HC is a "high-compression" variant of LZ4 that, I believe, changes point 1 above--the compressor finds more than one match between current and past data and looks for the best match to ensure the output is small. This improves compression *ratio* but lowers compression *speed* compared to LZ4. Decompression speed isn't hurt, though, so if you compress once and decompress many times and mostly want extremely cheap decompression, LZ4HC would make sense.

Note that even a fast compressor might not allow one core to saturate a large amount of bandwidth, like that provided by SSDs or fast in-datacenter links. There are even quicker compressors with lower ratios, sometimes used to [temporarily pack data in RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory_compression). [WKdm](https://github.com/berkus/wkdm) and [Density](https://github.com/centaurean/density) are two such compressors; one trait they share is acting on 4-byte *machine words* of input at a time rather than individual bytes. Sometimes specialized hardware can achieve very fast compression, like in [Samsung's Exynos chips](https://github.com/XileForce/Vindicator-S6/blob/master/drivers/memory/exynos-mcomp.c) or [Intel's QuickAssist technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-products/gigabit-server-adapters/quickassist-adapter-for-servers.html).

If you're interested in compressing more than LZ4 but with less CPU time than deflate, the author of LZ4 (Yann Collet) wrote a library called [Zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd)--here's a [blog post from Facebook at its stable release](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1658392934479273/smaller-and-faster-data-compression-with-zstandard/), background on the [finite state machines](http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/2013/12/finite-state-entropy-new-breed-of.html) used for compactly encoding info on repetitions, and a [detailed description in an RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kucherawy-dispatch-zstd). Its [fast modes](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases/tag/v1.3.4) could work in some LZ4-ish use cases. (Also, Apple developed [lzfse](https://github.com/lzfse/lzfse) on similar principles, and Google developed [gipfeli](https://github.com/google/gipfeli) as a 'medium' packer. Neither seemed to get much use in the outside world.)  Also, a couple projects aim to provide faster/lighter DEFLATE: [SLZ](http://1wt.eu/projects/libslz/), [patches to zlib by CloudFlare and Intel](http://www.snellman.net/blog/archive/2015-06-05-updated-zlib-benchmarks/). (There's also been [work on fast *decompression* on large modern CPU cores](https://dougallj.wordpress.com/2022/08/20/faster-zlib-deflate-decompression-on-the-apple-m1-and-x86/).)

Compared to the fastest compressors, those "medium" packers add a form of *entropy encoding*, which is to say they take advantage of how some bytes are more common than others and (in effect) put fewer bits in the output for the more common byte values.

If you're compressing one long stream, and going faster using more cores is potentially helpful, parallel compression is available for gzip through [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) and the zstd through the command-line tool's `-T` option (and in the library). (There are [various](http://conorstokes.github.io/compression/2016/02/15/an-LZ-codec-designed-for-SSE-decompression) experimental [packers](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/) out there too, but they exist more to push boundaries on speed or density, rather than for use today.)

So, in general, you have a pretty good spectrum of alternative compressors for different apps:

- For very fast compression: LZ4, zstd's lowest settings, or even weaker memory compressors
- For balanced compression: DEFLATE is the old standard; Zstd and brotli on low-to-medium settings are good alternatives for new uses
- For high compression: brotli, or Zstd on high settings
- For very high compression (like static content that's compressed once and served many times): brotli

As you move from LZ4 through DEFLATE to brotli you layer on more effort to predict and encode data and get more compression out at the cost of some speed.

As an aside, algorithms like brotli and zstd can generally outperform gzip--compress better at a given speed, or get the same compression faster--but this isn't actually because zlib did anything *wrong*. The main secret is probably that newer algos can use more memory: zlib dates to 1995 (and DEFLATE to [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP#PKZIP)). Back then RAM [cost](https://jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm) >3,000x as much as today, so just keeping 32KB of history made sense. Changes in CPUs over time may also be a factor: tons of of arithmetic (as used in finite state machines) is relatively cheaper than it used to be, and unpredictable `if`s (branches) are relatively more expensive.

Comment: Another page please, you forgot to describe LZ77 and how it differs, too :-)

Comment: @twotwotwo great write up. I know this might be beyond the scope, but what about https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string? Do you think this algorithm is faster than LZ4?

Comment: @NiCkNewman -- it's constrained by having to run in a JS virtual machine, whereas LZ4 can use optimized C or assembly. JavaScript engines are amazing at what they do, but still aren't like tuned native code. It's probably slower. It could always still be the right tool for your particular job, though.

Comment: I agree, adding in lz77/gzip would be great. how it differs from lzma.

Comment: @EvanCarroll DEFLATE--an LZ algorithm with Huffman coding to encode more common bytes in fewer bits--is the algorithm in gzip, and there are some generalizations about how it differs from high-compression algos in there. This probably isn't the right place for too many more specifics; if you want those, you could start on Wikipedia or other resources out there and keep researching as you hit terms you need defined.

Comment: @NiCkNewman I am the author of LZ-String. It is not faster than LZ4 since it is basically an LZW implementation with some tricks to fit its output in a String. It's a very old algorithm I chose because it was patent free when I wrote the lib, and is extremely simple to implement. In terms of speed it's probably comparable to zlib but it's worse in terms of compression ratio.