# Which one compress better in terms of size lz4 or zlib

Tags: compression, zlib, lz4

I need to use a compression technique. But can't decide between lz4 and zlib. I searched internet a little bit and lz4 is much recommended but i didn't find any data about the output size. So can anyone tell me which one is better in terms of final output size.

Comment: No, we cannot. If there is a universally best compression algorithm in existence, it has yet to be discovered. The best known ones will tend to each favor (slightly) a particular type of input pattern. This question is off-topic here anyway - it is not a programming question. Having said that, couldn't you just try the various candidate algorithms that you are considering and pick the best one yourself?

Answer (score 4):

[The lz4 Github repository has a benchmark that might be helpful](https://github.com/lz4/lz4). In general zlib will compress better, and take more time doing it, but your mileage may vary. Just try both on your data. Also look at [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this presentation: https://indico.cern.ch/event/631498/contributions/2553033/attachments/1443750/2223643/zlibvslz4presentation.pdf
[image]
also checkout [Difference: LZ77 vs. LZ4 vs. LZ4HC (compression algorithms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635496/difference-lz77-vs-lz4-vs-lz4hc-compression-algorithms)